# Shell function uses only the first argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt

I'm writing a script to customize a clean installation of Linux and there are several sections where it runs apt-get install. I've encountered some issues with my connection where it will occasionally stop working which can cause apt-get to fail and when this happens the script would continue to process the other commands.

The following script works, except now I'm hitting another issue: if the function is issued as `aptinstall firefox firefox-locale-en` for example, it only installs the first package that's listed.

I modified the script so that apt-get is run within a function that will retry if it fails up to 5 times:

```
# Install package - will retry download if connection fails up to 5 times and abort if unsuccessful
function aptinstall (){
local __pkg=$1
    set +x
    n=0
    until [ $n -ge 5 ]
    do
        apt-get install -y $__pkg && break
        n=$[$n+1]
        sleep 15 # Wait 15 seconds before trying to download and install packages again
    done
    if [ "$n" -eq 5 ]; then
        echo >&2 "An error has occurred. Please check your network connection."
        exit 1
    fi
```

Can anyone help me figure out why only the first package is installed? Thanks!

Comment: ```for __pkg do```

Comment: Replacing do with `for __pkg do` results in install.sh: line 39: syntax error near unexpected token `}' where the end of the function is. I must be missing something but I'm not sure what it is, my bash scripting skills have gotten pretty rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$1` use `"$@"`.

You don't need the local variable __pkg. In my opinion it unnecessarily complicates the script.

Also I noticed that you're using `$[expression]` for arithmetic evaluation.  That syntax is deprecated.  I would recommend using `$((expression))` instead.  For example, `n=$((n+1))`.

This is beyond the scope of your question, but if you are having problems with `apt-get` timing out, you may want to look into solutions to avoid that, such as setting up a local mirror.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this, it works great.

Comment: Or more compact, but not POSIX: `until (( ++n > 5 )); do __try__; done; if (( n > 5 )); then __error__; fi`